# css ionic 3 Animated text (sliding from right to left) when not all visibile

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm deploying an hybrid app with Ionic 3, and I would like to make the ion-title text "slide" from right to left, since when it's on mobile the text is not all visible (it's truncated).
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean like scrolling constantly across?

Answer (score 1):

Just Copied and Pasted this from https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/scrolling_text.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>

<!-- Styles --> 
<style style="text/css">
.example1 {
 height: 50px;  
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.example1 h3 {
 font-size: 3em;
 color: limegreen;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);    
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes example1 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->   
<div class="example1">
<h3>Scrolling text... </h3>
</div>
```